# Totient function sum over divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, totient-function

I would like to know if there is a closed form solution for

$$G(n)=\sum\limits_{d\mid n}(-1)^{\frac{n}{d}}\phi(d)$$

It seems quite likely there is since
$$\sum\limits_{d\mid n}\phi(d)=n$$

But I cant see any general way to approach this nutshell. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=2^km$ where $m$ is odd. For $(-1)^{\frac nd}$ to be odd, we need $d$ to be a multiple of $2^k$. So we could rewrite the sum as

$$\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^{\frac nd}\phi(d)=\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\2^k\nmid d}}\phi(d)-\sum_{\substack{d\mid n\\2^k\mid d}}\phi(d).$$

If $k=0$, the first sum in the RHS is empty and the result is simply $-n$. If $k\geq1$, $2^k\nmid d$ is equivalent to $d\mid\frac n2$. For the right sum we can write $d=2^ke$:

$$\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^{\frac nd}\phi(d)=\sum_{d\mid\frac n2}\phi(d)-\sum_{e\mid m}\phi(2^ke).$$

As $e$ is odd every time, $\phi(2^ke)=2^{k-1}\phi(e)$. So
$$\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^{\frac nd}\phi(d)=\sum_{d\mid\frac n2}\phi(d)-2^{k-1}\sum_{e\mid m}\phi(e).$$

The first sum in the RHS is $\frac n2$, the second is $2^{k-1}m=\frac n2$. Hence their difference is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be $G(n)=0$ if $n$ is even $>0$, $G(n)= -n$ if $n$ is odd $>0$.

Comment: Wow... that is quite a simple form.